# Can't log into ArrisDG860 router

Tags: passwords, wireless-router, connection, login, modem

I'm having a lot of trouble accessing the router login page, looking for some suggestions/assistance.

Several resets, several 30, then 60 second resets, power on, power off, no ability to edit the router's settings. However the internet is working fine and I can access any web page, and the speed is as fast as expected.

I just need to log into my router to change the SSID and password so any old body can't just look at the shared key and get into the router.

I have tried to do this on both wired and wireless configurations via my laptop.

I've done pings and ipconfig commands, and here is the information I got:

```
> Pinging 192.168.0.1 with 32 bytes of data: Reply from 192.168.0.1:
> bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64 Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms
> TTL=64 Reply from 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64 Reply from
> 192.168.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
> 
> Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
>     Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss), Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
>     Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms
> 
> C:\Users\Crystal>ipconfig /all
> 
> Windows IP Configuration
> 
>    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Crystal-PC    Primary Dns
> Suffix  . . . . . . . :    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid 
> IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . .
> . . . : No
> 
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter 2    Physical Address. . .
> . . . . . . : BC-77-37-68-29-CE    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
> Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter    Physical Address. . . .
> . . . . . : BC-77-37-68-29-CE    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
> Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1030    Physical Address. . . . .
> . . . . : BC-77-37-68-29-CD    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
> . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller    Physical Address. . . .
> . . . . . : 14-FE-B5-A8-B3-A4    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . :
> Yes    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    Link-local IPv6
> Address . . . . . : fe80::c4ae:73b1:2eb6:d894%10(Preferred)    IPv4
> Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.2(Preferred)    Subnet Mask .
> . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . .
> . : Wednesday, 02 April 2014 09:18:22 PM    Lease Expires . . . . . .
> . . . . : Wednesday, 02 April 2014 10:19:52 PM    Default Gateway . .
> . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . :
> 192.168.0.1    DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 236256949    DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-15-69-30-A0-14-FE-B5-A8-B3-
> 
>    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 200.1.104.35
>                                        200.1.104.36    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{9AFF45EB-2BA2-4FCC-9B32-AAADDF20B444}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{292EEC52-5A4F-4267-B2E6-947C91A83007}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{B98997E7-8AA2-471F-82C0-4F885C28C00E}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . .
> . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface    Physical Address. . . . .
> . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . .
> : No    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes    IPv6 Address. . . .
> . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:28eb:26b:41ac:3736(Pre rred)   
> Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . :
> fe80::28eb:26b:41ac:3736%20(Preferred)    Default Gateway . . . . . .
> . . . : ::    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{6B6F38E5-336E-4602-92A5-CBBFEC29E34D}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Description . . . . . . . . . .
> . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
> 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No   
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
> 
> C:\Users\Crystal>ipconfig /renew
> 
> Windows IP Configuration
> 
> No operation can be performed on Wireless Network Connection 3 while
> it has it media disconnected. No operation can be performed on
> Wireless Network Connection 2 while it has it media disconnected. No
> operation can be performed on Wireless Network Connection while it has
> its dia disconnected.
> 
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
> 
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
> 
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
> 
> Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    Link-local IPv6 Address . .
> . . . : fe80::c4ae:73b1:2eb6:d894%10    IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . .
> . . : 192.168.0.2    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
> Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{9AFF45EB-2BA2-4FCC-9B32-AAADDF20B444}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{292EEC52-5A4F-4267-B2E6-947C91A83007}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{B98997E7-8AA2-471F-82C0-4F885C28C00E}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
> 
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:
> 
>    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :    IPv6 Address. . . . . . . .
> . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6abd:28eb:26b:41ac:3736    Link-local IPv6 Address
> . . . . . : fe80::28eb:26b:41ac:3736%20    Default Gateway . . . . . .
> . . . : ::
> 
> Tunnel adapter isatap.{6B6F38E5-336E-4602-92A5-CBBFEC29E34D}:
> 
>    Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected   
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

I have never experienced something this difficult with logging into a router before. Using wireless access, I was able to load the login page about 30% of the time. So I have been able to connect to it. However, the password is supposed to be 'password', but I've tried that and several other possible defaults including a blank password, and everything fails. It keeps saying invalid password, and that's only when 192.168.0.1 actually loads at all. I can't get it to load even once when the laptop uses the direct line. The error I get says that the connection has timed out, even though the ping is greatly improved on the direct line (1ms as opposed to the average 34 or so ms via wi-fi)

Again, the internet itself moves smoothly without a hick. I just need to customize my ssid and password.

For further information, I have another wireless router set up on the same home account with a separate internet supply. I inspected the wireless channel usage, and the new router I can't get into uses channel 1 - 3 while the other uses 4 - 7 so there's no conflict whatsoever. And it's evident as I'm on one network with my phone and the other with my laptop and there's no lag or disturbance, and I'm able to get into the other router's login page fine.

Any help or advice is really appreciated, I'm one of those strange people who can't leave something alone until it's fixed. :V

P.S: I tried this while taking my antivirus realtime scan and firewall off, as well. Out of ideas. Note, I have tried this on other devices without these firewalls in place. All the devices can still enter my other router/modem fine without a single delay but can't get this one to respond.

P.p.s: I've called my ISP and they have no idea why it's doing that either. All the tech could do was write a report because she can log into my router/modem fine from her console using admin/password.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information like what type of a router do you have, model, etc. 1) Make sure all your Antivirus software are disabled, what browser do you use? Don't use Internet explore, Microsoft updated their IE with 1024bit encryption key, so if your router is old...use Firefox. 2) Find out what is the default IP address for your router if its (192.168.0.1) then assign you computer with static IP address like (192.168.0.5) try to connect one more time. 3) Based on the router model you might going to need to do a memory clear reset that might help to get you in, hope this was helpful.

Comment: SQL, thanks for your response. My mistake, I don't know why I said router, it is a modem that issues IP addresses.
Called the ISP and the tech says she can access my modem with no problems using the old admin/password. I took off all my firewalls, tried this from even a mobile phone, and yet no luck. 

1. The modem is new - I used firefox, iexplore and chrome, all of which have timed out. (Windows 7 here) -  it says "website 192.168.0.1 is online but isn't responding to connection attempts".

Comment: oh and yes your comment is very helpful so far, it helps me know what I'm doing wrong/right. Can you tell me how to do a memory clear reset? It is an ArrisDG860 MODEM btw. My mistake again on the router comment